# Outer div height of highest inner div without javascript

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a css only layout, where the outer div, which contains > 2 inner divs automatically has the height of the highest inner div. The real world example would be, one div being the background, the other one being the content. I experimented with `position: absolute` and `position: relative`, like setting the higher one to relative and the other one to absolute works. But the problem is that both are dynamic and I do not know beforehand which will be higher. See the snippet.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  outline: 5px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  background: #f3fa;
  color: #000;
}

.bg img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* in #first the content is tiny, so setting the .bg position: relative makes the outer the same height as the .bg here */
#first .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* in the #second the content is higher, so setting it to position: relative makes the outer the same height as the .content here */
#second .content {
  position: relative;
}

#second .bg {
  position: absolute;
}

#third .inner1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* the problem is i do not know which is higher, sometimes the bg image, sometimes the content */
#third .inner1 {
  /* ??? */
}

#third .inner2 {
  /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>I am the first content and the bg image is 200x100 and self  is not that high</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="second" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>I am second content and should make <code>.outer</code> higher Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="third" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>I do not know</p>
    <p>which is higher <code>.bg</code> or <code>.content</code> and want neither to be cut or no scroll bars</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you need. Does removing all settings of absolute fix it?

Comment: its hard to describe. the background image sometimes is higher, then the containing div should be the height of the background image. if instead, the content is so much, that it does not "fit" the area of the background image, the background containing div should extend to fit the content. The background image can then be cut like in `object-fit: cover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid and make both of them on the same grid track:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  float:left;
  width: 150px;
  outline: 5px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
}
.outer > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}

.content {
  background: #f3fa;
  color: #000;
}

.bg img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>I am the first content and the bg image is 200x100 and self  is not that high</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="second" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>I am second content and should make <code>.outer</code> higher Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="third" class="outer">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>I do not know</p>
    <p>which is higher <code>.bg</code> or <code>.content</code> and want neither to be cut or no scroll bars</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any possible solution without grids in css only?